# Perl in Windows Vista 32bit?

Tags: perl, windows-vista

I want to practice Perl in Windows Vista 32bit, how can I do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

download Active perl and enjoy

http://www.activestate.com/activeperl

Comment: ..enjoy the CPAN client being a complete pain, I guess.

Answer (score 8):

Just an alternative to active perl is [strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), each has it's own merits to use, but I would say that the initially active perl is better implemented (for instance it implements the .pl extension by default, adds perl to the PATH variable etc.) but strawberry perl makes it incredibly easy to install new modules, and generally is really good to use as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl).

Answer (score 1):

[ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) is a good Windows Perl interpreter